# MongoDb : Update a Record & push to an array. Cannot update 'addresses.0' and 'addresses.0.insertupdate' at the same time

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection **names** with this schema.

```
    {
    name: "A1",
    addresses : 
   [
    {
    add1 : "a1",
    add2 : "a2",
    insertupdate:[
            {
            "mode" : "i" ,
            "user" : "abcd"
            }
                 ]
    }
    ,
    {
    add1 : "a3",
    add2 : "a4",
    insertupdate:[
            {
            "mode" : "i",
            "user" : "pqrs"
            }
              ]
    }
   ],
   insertupdate:[
            {
            "mode" : "i",
            "user" : "pqrs"
            }
   ]
  }
```

**What I am trying to do :**

I want to update record add1 = "a1" as add2 = "a5" & push a record inside addresses.insertupdate as well as insertupdate.

**What i tried :**

```
db.names.update({name:"A1",addresses.add1:"a1"},
{
$set : {
        addresses.$ : 
        {
        "add2":"a5"
        }
       },
$push : {
    "insertupdate" : {"mode":"u","user":"xyz"},
    "addresses.$.insertupdate" : {"mode":"u","user":"xyz"}
       }
}
);
```

**Error I got :**

> Cannot update 'addresses.0' and 'addresses.0.insertupdate' at the same
>   time

**Edit :**

This command was successful. However it wont let me set my values. i.e. I need a way out to use a set & push with the positional operator at the same time.

```
 db.names.update(
 {"name":"A1", "addresses.add1":"a1"}, 
 {$push:{
        "insertupdate":{"mode":"u","user":"xyz"},
        "addresses.$.insertupdate":{"mode":"u","user":"xyz"}
        } 
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment in one of my questions pointed me to the answer  [mongodb update using positional operator $ removes other fields :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008184/mongodb-update-using-positional-operator-removes-other-fields)

```
db.names.update({name:"A1",addresses.add1:"a1"},
{
$set : {
        "addresses.$.add2" : "a5"        
       },
$push : {
    "insertupdate" : {"mode":"u","user":"xyz"},
    "addresses.$.insertupdate" : {"mode":"u","user":"xyz"}
       }
}
);
```