# mongodb update using positional operator $ removes other fields :

Tags: mongodb

I have this schema (MongoDb : 3.2.6) :

```
> db.arrObject.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("576ce19479bd1761a560c14d"),
        "name" : "abcd",
        "addresses" : [
                {       "add1" : "a1",
                        "add2" : "a2",
                        "add3" : "a3"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("576ce19e79bd1761a560c14e"),
        "name" : "pqrs",
        "addresses" : [
                {
                        "add1" : "a1",
                        "add2" : "a2",
                        "add3" : "a3"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

**What I am trying to do :**

I am trying to update add2 field with a45 for addresses.add1 = "a1" & name = "abcd" & keep add1 & add3 fields intact.

**What I did :**

```
db.arrObject.update( 
   {"name":"abcd","addresses.add1":"a1"},
   {$set:{"addresses.$" : {"add2":"a45"}}}
    )
```

**What I obtained  :**

```
> db.arrObject.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("576ce19479bd1761a560c14d"),
        "name" : "abcd",
        "addresses" : [
                {
                        "add2" : "a45"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("576ce19e79bd1761a560c14e"),
        "name" : "pqrs",
        "addresses" : [
                {
                        "add1" : "a1",
                        "add2" : "a2",
                        "add3" : "a3"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

**i.e.** add1 & add3 field got removed.

I don't have the liberty to add each field in update statement.
How can i update fields using positional operator & keep other fields intact.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932924/how-to-solve-mongodb-related-issue-efficiently) and please add listings instead of screenshots to your qestion. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the dot notation like `db.arrObject.update({ "name": "abcd", "addresses.add1": "a1" },{ "$set": {"addresses.$.add2": "a45" } })`?

Comment: @chridam yes I tried it & it works. would like to know the difference between the syntax.

Comment: The difference is that the query specified in the question actually replaces the value of the array, whereas the query specified in the comment finds the key specified and replaces it's value, leaving other fields intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just summarized the solution mentioned in the comment for others benefit. Please use dot notation. Sample below:-

```
db.arrObject.update({ "name": "abcd", "addresses.add1": "a1" },{ "$set": {"addresses.$.add2": "a45" } })
```